# Sorting list based upon string stored in date format

Tags: javascript

So I have an app which allows people to add items, and assign a 'date' to them. This 'date' isn't an ISO stored date, instead it's a literal string.

For example:

- December 2020
- February 2022
- January 2021

And so on.. In this case, I'd want to order them from newest to oldest, so it'd be this order:

- February 2022
- January 2021
- December 2020

It'd be feasible to convert from string to date (I guess?), but this doesn't feel very efficient.

Is there a way to easily sort strings like this in JavaScript?

Comment: Convert the entire list to dates before sorting them.

Comment: Converting from string to date is pretty much your only option here.

Comment: when saving data, one should think of ways to use the data later on... it would be better to save as a date like `${year}-${month}-01` and then later, display only Month and Year, that way you would be able to do all sort of features, even display the date in other languages for example...